# How do I access a field in an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models that are associated with eachother, every Entry can have one category. Inversely I guess that Category could also have many entries.

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
end
```

My Schema for the two models looks like this:

```
create_table "categories", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
end

create_table "entries", :force => true do |t|
  t.text     "description"
  t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  t.text     "address"
  t.float    "longitude"
  t.float    "latitude"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "category_id"
end
```

My index page is based on @entries.all which currently builds an array of the data taken from the Entry model. My index page shows the category_id which is fine but what would be better, would be to extract the name from the join model of Category.

So if entry.category_id gives me the id how can I get the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You association looks incorrect. According to your db schema, the relationship is Category has_many entries, and Entry belongs_to Category. If judging from your models, the categories table should have entry_id instead of entries table having category_id.

To refactor, if your logic is to only allow one category per entry, it's easy.

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :entries
end

# Then `entries` table should have one field `category_id`

# To access an entry's category as per you requested:
@entry.category
```

If your logic is one entry may have more than one entries, you need to use many to many relationship and an intermediate table.

Comment: Ah! That works, I got my logic in a twist and have since experimented a little more with these, and understand it much better. Thanks to @billy chan